# Kusto: Query to get http status codes

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql, azure-container-apps

I am trying to query Azure container apps to create a custom alert for when there is an Http status code of 400.

I am new to kusto. I attempted the below query:

```
CIEventsAudit
| where StatusCode == 400
| sort by TimeGenerated desc
| limit 100
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you can post that we can help you modify it to your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query attempt is on the right track. [`CIEventsAudit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/cieventsaudit) is the table to be used for retrieving the http status code logs for container apps.

The below query which you already tried gives you the logs that are limited to the count`100` when they are having http status code `400`. And sort the logs in the descending order wrt `TimeGenerated` field.

```bash
CIEventsAudit
| where StatusCode == 400
| sort by TimeGenerated desc
| limit 100
```

*Alternatively, you can also use below query to achieve your requirement.*

```bash
CIEventsAudit
| where OperationName contains "HttpRequest"
| where OperationStatus == 400
| sort by TimeGenerated desc
| limit 100
```

Once you are done with adding either of the above queries, you can create an alert rule with `custom log search signal` as shown below.
Under `Actions`, provide the necessary action group details to meet your requirements.

[image]